# What to compare this series to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does $\sum_{n=1}^∞ n^{1/5}sin(\dfrac{1}{n}) $ converge or diverge?

I tried the ratio and root test, but they're both inconclusive. I'm thinking that I need to use the comparison test but I have no idea what to compare it to.

Comment: How does $\sin x$ behave for $x \to 0$?

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum n^{1/5}\sin\frac1n=\sum n^{-4/5}\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}=\infty
$$
since $\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}\to1$ and $\sum n^{-4/5}=\infty$.